# Modifying the layout on pages in NopCommerce 2.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I’m trying to modify the layout on some pages in NopCommerce 2.5, e.g.. For starters changing the layout of “about us” from a three column page to a two column page and also make some changes to the layout of pages that are accessed via URL strings like www.mysite.com /c/2/computers e.g.. Categories and Manufacturers.

I’m able to do this with pages like Contact Us and Home but I can’t seem to find the files in VWD to modify them. Does anyone know where to go to find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to change the layout of category page or manufacturer page, you should edit the files

'Nop.Web\Views\Catalog\CategoryTemplate.ProductsInGridOrLines.cshtml'

or

'Nop.Web\Views\Catalog\ManufacturerTemplate.ProductsInGridOrLines.cshtml' respectively.